# rsyslog inside docker containers => "rsyslogd is not running ... failed"

Tags: docker, rsyslog

I am running rsyslog within docker containers to send UDP messages to logstash.

When I log into the docker container, and type:

```
service rsyslog status
```

shows:

```
rsyslogd is not running ... failed!
```

However, while I am in the container, if I type:

```
service rsyslog start
```

It starts up perfectly with no errors and no real sign of why it failed at the start

I CAN NOT FIGURE OUT WHY IT IS FAILING!!!!

*The rsyslog conf file has not been modified except the Modules to allow for imfile.  The rsyslog.conf is as follows:

```
#  /etc/rsyslog.conf    Configuration file for rsyslog.
#
#                       For more information see
#                       /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-doc/html/rsyslog_conf.html
#################
#### MODULES ####
#################
module(load="imfile" PollingInterval="10")
module(load="imuxsock" )  # provides support for local system logging
module(load="immark")  #provides --MARK-- message capability

###########################
#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
###########################

#
# Use traditional timestamp format.
# To enable high precision timestamps, comment out the following line.
#
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

#
# Set the default permissions for all log files.
#
$FileOwner root
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0644
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022

#
# Where to place spool and state files
#
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

#
# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
#
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf


###############
#### RULES ####
###############

#
# First some standard log files.  Log by facility.
#
auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog
#cron.*                         /var/log/cron.log
daemon.*                        -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*                          -/var/log/kern.log
lpr.*                           -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*                          -/var/log/mail.log
user.*                          -/var/log/user.log

#
# Logging for the mail system.  Split it up so that
# it is easy to write scripts to parse these files.
#
mail.info                       -/var/log/mail.info
mail.warn                       -/var/log/mail.warn
mail.err                        /var/log/mail.err

#
# Logging for INN news system.
#
news.crit                       /var/log/news/news.crit
news.err                        /var/log/news/news.err
news.notice                     -/var/log/news/news.notice

#
# Some "catch-all" log files.
#
*.=debug;\
        auth,authpriv.none;\
        news.none;mail.none     -/var/log/debug
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
        auth,authpriv.none;\
        cron,daemon.none;\
        mail,news.none          -/var/log/messages

#
# Emergencies are sent to everybody logged in.
#
*.emerg                         :omusrmsg:*

#
# I like to have messages displayed on the console, but only on a virtual
# console I usually leave idle.
#
#daemon,mail.*;\
#       news.=crit;news.=err;news.=notice;\
#       *.=debug;*.=info;\
#       *.=notice;*.=warn       /dev/tty8

# The named pipe /dev/xconsole is for the `xconsole' utility.  To use it,
# you must invoke `xconsole' with the `-file' option:
#
#    $ xconsole -file /dev/xconsole [...]
#
# NOTE: adjust the list below, or you'll go crazy if you have a reasonably
#      busy site..
#
daemon.*;mail.*;\
        news.err;\
        *.=debug;*.=info;\
        *.=notice;*.=warn       |/dev/xconsole
```

*I have a script file that starts rsyslog

```
if [[ -z "$(pgrep rsyslog)" ]]; then
  echo "starting rsyslog"
  service rsyslog start
fi
```

My conf file is as follows:

```
##Get Nginx Error Logs
$InputFileName /var/log/nginx/error.log
$InputFileTag http-error
$InputFileStateFile stat-nginx-error
$InputFileSeverity error
$InputFileFacility local7
$InputRunFileMonitor

#GRAB PHP-FPM ACCESS LOGS
$InputFileName /var/log/php-fpm/access_log
$InputFileTag php-fpm-access
$InputFileStateFile stat-php-fpm-access
$InputFileSeverity info
$InputFileFacility local7
$InputRunFileMonitor

#GRAB PHP-FPM ERROR LOGS
$InputFileName /var/log/php-fpm/error_log
$InputFileTag php-fpm-error
$InputFileStateFile stat-php-fpm-error
$InputFileSeverity error
$InputFileFacility local7
$InputRunFileMonitor

#Json Template

template(name="json_temp" type="list")
  { constant(value="{")
    constant(value="\"@timestamp\":\"")         property(name="timegenerated" dateFormat="rfc3339")
    constant(value="\",\"message\":\"")         property(name="msg")
    constant(value="\",\"severity_label\":\"")  property(name="syslogseverity-text")
    constant(value="\",\"severity\":\"")        property(name="syslogseverity")
    constant(value="\",\"facility_label\":\"")  property(name="syslogfacility-text")
    constant(value="\",\"facility\":\"")        property(name="syslogfacility")
    constant(value="\",\"program\":\"")         property(name="programname")
    constant(value="\",\"pid\":\"")             property(name="procid")
    constant(value="\",\"rawmsg\":\"")          property(name="rawmsg")
    constant(value="\",\"syslogtag\":\"")       property(name="syslogtag")
    constant(value="\"}\n")
  }

if $programname == 'http-error' then @ip.address:port;json_temp
if $programname == 'http-error' then stop
if $programname == 'php-fpm-access' then @ip.address:port;json_temp
if $programname == 'php-fpm-access' then stop
if $programname == 'php-fpm-error' then @ip.address:port;json_temp
if $programname == 'php-fpm-error' then stop


*.* @ip.address:port;json_temp
```

Any help would be awesome because I do not understand why it is not starting up.

Cheers

Comment: I just encounter the the same issue. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: I did, but it was a bit of a hack.  Because I was only interested in the php and nginx logs,  I brought my conf file into the rsyslog.conf and got rid of the  code I wasn't directly using.  Similar to what I found [here](https://gist.github.com/amoslanka/6720707).  If that doesn't work it could be a group privilege issue for your ngninx and php log files.

Answer (score 5):

We bumped upon the same issue on a Docker 17.03.2-ce image created on CentOS 7.3.1611. The solution is in verifying `/etc/rsyslog.conf` as per [this](https://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2014/09/running-syslog-within-a-docker-container/) documentation. Basically, in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

- Remove $ModLoad imjournal
- Set $OmitLocalLogging to off
- Make sure $ModLoad imuxsock is present
- Comment out: $IMJournalStateFile imjournal.state

Finally, note that running the `rsyslogd` or anything else, is the responsibility of the program that is being run inside the container. It is not going to get launched, automatically.

Answer (score 3):

This is my rsyslog.conf in docker container(centos7):

```
$> cat /etc/rsyslog.conf |grep -vE '^$|^#'
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
$OmitLocalLogging off
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log
```

Also i changed /etc/rsyslog.d/listen.conf

```
#$SystemLogSocketName /run/systemd/journal/syslog
```

And then

```
$> rsyslogd -n
```

Thanks @elinax

More info at https://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2014/09/running-syslog-within-a-docker-container/

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in file entrypoint.sh:

```
sudo service rsyslog start
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue when running mysql container on Fedora.

https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/579

The best workaround I found was in this gist:

https://gist.github.com/vicenterusso/ae6d6c903b790e5dae91c339c1ce2ba8

Basically, I add the `ulimits` to my docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  service-name:
    image: <your-image>
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      nofile:
        soft: 20000
        hard: 40000
```